# How to protect routes under /admin, when get /admin/whatever check login status

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a admin backend want to protect by checking login status. I have write a /admin route to check if user is logged in or not, if not it should redirect to /admin/login, if yes, it should render login. But how to extend this to including /admin/test and /admin/whateveritbe, so every time user try to visit /admin/*, it should check user is logged in or not.

my /admin route:

```
app.get('/admin', Admin.index);
```

check logged in or not:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
if (req.session.user == null){
    if (req.cookies.userName == undefined || req.cookies.password == undefined){
        res.redirect('/admin/login');
    } else {
        var data = {
            userName: req.cookies.userName,
            password: req.cookies.password
        }
        AccountManager.AutoLogin(data, function(err, result){
            if (!err) {
                console.log('login: '+result);
                req.session.user = result;
                res.render('admin/index', { title: 'Admin Control Center' });
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/admin/login');
            }
        });
    }
} else {
    res.render('admin/index', { title: 'Admin Control Center' });
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You can check login status by this function

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  // if they aren't redirect them
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

and use this in your admin route like this:

```
app.get('/admin', isLoggedIn, function (req, res){
  // do your code;
});
```